# What are the FTP ports?

Tags: firewall, ftp

Can you tell me what are the ports that need to be open for FTP?

Comment: I put your question title into Google and found more answers than you will ever need.

Comment: Please see the [Protocol overview](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol#Protocol_overview) on Wikipedia FTP page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The FTP server always receives traffic on port 21. It sends out traffic with a source port of 20 while using active ftp and with a a random port greater than or equal to 1024 while using passive ftp.

Comment: The second sentence deserves some clarification: In the *Active* mode transfer, the *client* starts listening on a random port and the server connects to back it (from its source port 20 – source ports are usually not interesting when comes to networking/firewall). In the *Passive* mode transfer, the *server* starts listening on a random port and the client connects to it. In both cases, for the random ports, the client/server typically allows configuring the port range.

Answer (score 1):

[Well-known Port Numbers](http://www.iana.org/assignments/port-numbers)

Comment: While this is somewhat useful, I doubt it is enough for the person asking to understand ftp enough to permit it through a firewall/nat which is the most likely real question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a list of Internet socket port numbers used by protocols of the Transport Layer of the Internet Protocol Suite for the establishment of host-to-host communications.Pls see the 20 th and 21 entry.The FTP server always receives traffic on port 21. It sends out traffic with a source port of 20

[image]

[image]

If u need whole list, go to the following link..

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers

Comment: As a picture? really?

Answer (score -2):

FTP uses port 21, you can forward the port in your firewall

Comment: This answer is incomplete.  Forwarding only port 21 will not work 99% of the time.